# How to restrict the dynamic height of the tallest descendant in a flexbox layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox wrapper which has two descendants. They both have dynamic height. The second block could be higher than the first one, and I would like to limit the height of the second block to the same as the height of the first one.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;

  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}



.left {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
}

.first {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.second {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: green;
}


/*desired result */
.fixed-height {
  height: 100px;
}

.overflow-value {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper fixed-height">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right overflow-value">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the provided example, there two wrappers: the first one is the current wrapper, where the wrapper has the height of the tallest child. And the second one is the desired result (I added height to the wrapper, but I couldn't do it in real application)

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/sergiussheman/pen/YBLWVj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using `flexbox` then there is a way to force the container to just take the height of specific child into account - this can be done by forcing the contents of the second item out of layout context with `position: absolute`. Unfortunately, this requires adding another wrapper inside the `.right` element. In addition, having the items positioned absolutely inside the second item will mean that the width of the contents will not be propagated to the `.right` element, but since your example has an explicit width set, then it works in this case. The code with those modifications is below:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;

  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}



.left {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}

.first {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.second {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: green;
}

.right-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="right-wrapper">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```